# Odata with Asp.net and angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am following up in the course AngularJS Front to Back with Web API using ASP.net, we are trying to do queries using ODATA so i added this code in the `ProductController` in the WebAPI

```cs
// GET: api/Products
[EnableQuery()]
public IQueryable<Product> Get()
{
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    return productRepository.Retrieve().AsQueryable();
}
```

then added the below code in the productcontroller in the angular code:

```
function ProductListCtrl(productResource) {
    var vm = this;

    productResource.query({$skip:1, $top:3}, function (data) {
        vm.products = data;
 })
```

but when I try to run it gives me the below error:

> angular.js:12701 GET http://localhost:59302//api/products?$skip=1&$top=3 400 (Bad Request)
>   Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. No non-OData HTTP route registered.","exceptionMessage":"No non-OData HTTP route registered.",.....

Comment: Have you wired your route to model? If you have `ProductController` then route must be `...\Product`, not `products`. I believe, it is case sensitive.

Comment: returning IQueryable in your controller is a bad idea. That's not data, IQueryable is a way of building up your query but it doesn't actually execute anything until you do a ToList() or specifically call the execution. There is no reason to return that from your controller and it will be cause of many issues if you go down that route.

Comment: This is the tutorial instructions, I just want to get the idea . the model is Products not product

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have odataConfiguration?? Where's you EDM configuration?

In your config file you need something like that:

```
   public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code:
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

Comment: More information you can get there:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: What is the EDM configuration, I am new to asp.net and c#, can you please explain further?, I found a WebApiConfig file in  the App_start, is that what you meant?

Comment: EDM - entity data manager. You should configure your configuration to provide OData routing.